# Best Practise: Linking to WPMU sites from other sites

Tags: multisite, switch-to-blog

I'm digging through WPSE, and WP Codex/Core, and I am looking for essentially `wpmu_blog_link( $blog_id )`, which would essentially be `home_url()` with a parameter to pass the `blog_id`. I could easily just do

```
<a href="/my_other_blog/">Link to blog 2</a>
```

but it seems a little more hard-coded than necessary, and would break between development (localhost) and live.

There's always

```
function blog_home_url( $blog_id ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $url = home_url();
    restore_current_blog();
    return $url;
}

...

<a href="<?php echo blog_name_url( 2 ) ?>">Link to Blog 2</a>
```

Just seeing if there is anything built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer but...

[`get_blogaddress_by_name`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blogaddress_by_name) or [`get_blogaddress_by_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blogaddress_by_id) look to me like what you need. Both return the full blog URL.

Comment: You are a beautiful creature. Thanks muchly! This is only my 3rd WPMU, so still a little green behind the ears!